# Lightning :select is not showing the error message using v.errors

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning Select is not displaying the error message

```
<lightning:select label="Case Template" variant="standard" value="{! v.objtype.Quick_Code_Name__c }" required="true" aura:id="inputtemp" name = "Case Template" messageWhenValueMissing="Choose one!"><!--  value="{!v.selectedValue}"-->
                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option"  >
                                            <option  text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.value}"> {!option} </option>
                                        </aura:iteration>
                                    </lightning:select>


 var inputtemp1 = component.find("inputtemp");
 var value1 = inputtemp1.get("v.value");

    if(value1 != "--- None ---" && value1 != undefined && value1 != null) {
                    inputtemp.set("v.errors", null);
    } else {
        alert("Test");
        inputtemp.set("v.errors", [{message:"Case Template is Required."}]);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `required="true"`?

Comment: I have updated the Code can you please check once...???

Comment: check this : value1.length>0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use required, onchange and messageWhenValueMissing attributes. 
please try the example below

```
<aura:attribute name="optns" type="String[]" default="a,b,c"/>
<lightning:select aura:id="select" name="select" 
                  label="Select an Option" 
                  required="true" onchange="{! c.onChange }" 
                  messageWhenValueMissing="Choose one!">
    <option value="">-- None --</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.optns}" var="option">
            <option value="{!option}" text="{!option}"></option>
        </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of focus() method available in lightning:input/select

You can use:

```
var allValid = cmp.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) { //inputCmp.reportValidity(); inputCmp.focus(); return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity(); }, true);
```

Then reset the focus to appropriate field and you'll see the all errors listed under the field.